# Remove string which has <html> and <body> part

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I want to remove text in between the some html tags.

```
For example : <html xmln><head>............<body lang="">after this I need the text
```

I am trying to remove `<html> to <body>` part. I have used **substring** methode and it is working. But in real scenario this `<html ..>` ... can come multiple times. I have to remove only those and text in between them.
Any help will be appreciated 
I have tried substring and regex but not able remove repeated things.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something like this..

```
string.replace(/(<html)(.*?)(<body lang="">)/g, '');
```